# sendDeviceEventWIthName not sending event

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to send an event through react native bridge using `sendDeviceEventWithName`.

I have created a class which only has three methods, basic init, a react method called `sendDeviceNotification` which sends a device event and `sendNotification`, which prints a test string and then calls `sendDeviceEventWithName`.

If I call the react method, the JS gets the event no problem.
However, if I call the native method, the JS cannot get the event.

I initialize the class object in AppDelegate.m:

```
self.km = [[KitManager alloc] init];
```

Then when I get a push notification I call the method

```
[self.km sendNotification];
```

which has the body

```
NSLog(@"Notification sent");
    [self.bridge.eventDispatcher sendDeviceEventWithName:@"testEventSent" body:@{@"SOURCE": @"XC"}];
}
```

I can see the xcode log that the NSLog has printed, but I don't get the event.
Any idea why or how I should be correctly setting up device events?

Answer (score 1):

I had to subclass RCTEventEmitter and then use NSNotificationCenter to route events.